# Mixed usage of UTF-8 and ASCII encodings?

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I am currently parsing large text files with Python 2.7, some of which were originally encoded in Unicode or UTF-8.

For modules containing functions which directly interact with strings in UTF-8, I included `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file, but for functions which work with only ascii, I did not bother.

Eventually, these modules lead to larger modules, and all the parsed strings gets mixed together. Is it good practice to include `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at top of every file?

Is there a benefit to this?

Comment: Not only any ASCII symbol is a valid UTF-8, but every part of a UTF-8 encoded character is equal to ASCII code of an ASCII symbol if and only if it is a single-byte ASCII character. That means, part of the encoded multi-byte codepoint can never be an ascii character. So it is easy to search for ascii substrings, as if the string was pure ASCII.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` declares the encoding of the source file **only**. It has nothing to do whatsoever with the way Python handles input or output. It just means you can write string literals and comments using UTF-8.

Here's the effect of a coding declaration. Let's say I have a program

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# the following prints the Dutch word "één"
print(u"\xe9\xe9n")
```

This does exactly what the comment says. But if I remove the `coding` declaration, it crashes:

```
File "a.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file a.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Note that line 1 is the *comment*. The program can be fixed by removing the comment, leaving just

```
print(u"\xe9\xe9n")
```

which still behaves exactly the same as the first program.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding how encodings work, but if I add strings to an object in a function with # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-, and add other strings to the same object in a function without # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-, is there no difference than as if # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- were added to both functions?

Comment: @supernoobie: there is absolutely no difference. It's just a declaration of how the source code is encoded, not how the program should behave.

Comment: Question regarding your last edit, by "The program can be fixed by removing that, leaving just" doesn't that make the third code block exactly like the second block (with the coding declaration removed), why wouldn't it error the second time around?

Comment: @supernoobie: it errs in the second version because the comment contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Small nit: `coding` *declares*, not changes, the encoding of the source file.  The coder must actually save the file in the declared encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Every ASCII file is also a valid UTF-8. Don't worry about treating your ASCII files as UTF-8 files, no conversion necessary, no increase in size.